# How to verify and manage the app.config file in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, visual-studio, connection-string, designer

I am making a WPF application in Visual Studio 2015. The database layer is using Entity Framework, which generated a connection string in the app.config file. The database connection works and the app runs. Nonetheless, at design-time, Visual Studio complains about there being "no connection string named in the application configuration file" -- but there is.

Since it seems to resolve itself as run-time, I ignored the warnings up until now. However, now the issue is interfering with the design process -- Visual Studio is claiming not being able to make instances of classes that use the connection.

I have tried moving the app.config around into various positions in the project structure, renaming it to match the app's name, cleaning and rebuilding the project.

I believe that, at design-time, not all files are referencing the same app.config. Something about my project structure must be off.

How can I determine and/or change the path that EF is following to the app.config?

The XML from the app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="MYAPPSNAME" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MYDBNAME.csdl|res://*/MYDBNAME.ssdl|res://*/MYDBNAME.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=193.169.2.123;user id=devs;password=*********;persistsecurityinfo=True;convertzerodatetime=True;database=MYDBNAME&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"  /></connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is your EF in the same project or is it a seperate dll?  At run time, connection string is read from the project's .config, at design time, it is read from the dll's .config file

Comment: Have you checked what connection string name your EntityFramework DbContext is expecting to see inside you app.config? is MYAPPSNAME correct?

Comment: I did check that, yes, and the connection string was all correct - for some reason, the project just can't see/understand it while at design-time. Seems like at run-time it finds the app.config and reads it and makes the connection, no problem. :) I found a work-around here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/257ca21a-15cd-4d21-84df-79cc6bcbe546/getting-a-no-connection-string-named-cound-be-found-in-the-application-config-file-error-and-i?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/257ca21a-15cd-4d21-84df-79cc6bcbe546/getting-a-no-connection-string-named-cound-be-found-in-the-application-config-file-error-and-i?forum=wpf

Essentially, I add the following to the constructors of classes that establish a database connection; it checks if the project is in Designer Mode, and if so, returns before trying to make a database connection.

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())) 
        return;
```

In this way, I avoid the issue of Visual Studio trying to make a db connection from the designer, so it doesn't complain and allows me to design freely. At run-time, still no issues. :)

Still not entirely sure of the source of the problem -- I am still guessing that at design-time, the app.config file is not fully read/parsed, so the designer is complaining about not having enough information to construct such classes.

Answer (score -1):

If it shows up in Solution Explorer then properties will show you where it is.  You should be able to open and edit it right there.

If app.config is not in Solution Explorer it should be in the same folder has the MainWindow. Make sure you also add (Add Existing) in the project in Visual Studio. The file should show up in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately that's not quite my problem. The App.Config is visible and "included" in my project...but evidently some of the Entity Framework files are not reading it correctly until run-time.

Comment: Have you verified you can read app.config directly in design mode?

Comment: Yes. I can read the XML of the app.config file. The Visual Studio designer says it cannot find a connection string which is indeed there, or under slightly different circumstances, it says the provider is not defined, while in fact it is. Very frustrating =)

Comment: I have added the XML to my question. Thank you very much for your time. As you can see, the connection string is well-formed and the data provider is registered in the "entity framework" section.

Comment: Man dude I give up.  "Please post how you are reading the XML"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I am not parsing the XML. .NET is doing it. I posted the XML in an edit in the question.

Comment: So you lied when you answered yes to "Have you verified you can read app.config directly in design mode?"   You have NOT read the config in C#.  I am done.